# Volley DELETE request throws 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: java, android, json, request, android-volley

I try to send a DELETE request to my server, but I get a 400 bad request error code back. I search a lot but I can't find any solution that help. When I try it with Postman, the request works fine.

This is how the curl command from Postman looks:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://blablabla.de' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"deviceId":"33",
"factoryReset":"0"
}'
```

This is my Java code:

```
    public void unlinkDevice(String deviceId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "unlinkDevice: " + deviceId);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("deviceId", deviceId);
        jsonObject.put("factoryReset", 0);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            listener.onDeviceUnlink(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            listener.onError(error);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Cookie", StartApplication.getCookie());
            return headers;
        }
    };

    queue.addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

I also try it without to set the Content-Type in the header, but when I get a 415 error and I also removed the getBodyContentType() method, but this also changed nothing.

Any other ideas that can help ?

Comment: can you confirm the factoryReset is a integer on String? if its a string and you are passing integer that may be causing the issue.

Comment: on the server its handle as a String, but also when I change "factoryReset", 0 to "factoryReset","0" I get a 400 back

Comment: does your postman runs fine? by changing the factoryReset to integer

Comment: yes this works also via Postman

Comment: can you confirm the endpoint you are trying to hit is same for the app as well as for the postman.

Comment: yes and on the server the bad request is only throw if(entity.size() != 2 || !entity.containsKey("deviceId") || !entity.containsKey("factoryReset"))

Comment: and what response do you expect after this? is it a JSON response or just a string message?

Comment: currently only a 200 its send back, with an blank json. I know that volley throw in this case an error but not the 400, it would throw a json exception

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the reason... in volley the body is ignored when you use a DELETE request